# Can someone help me save simple strings in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios4, plist, nsdictionary

I've been trying to save strings in Xcode such as email and password so i can open them in different view, So far every attempt for the past 2 weeks have failed.

does anyone have a working way, and if so can you post the code.

Thanks

*edit***

Almost done just having an error here

```
(MemberPage *)initWithString: (NSString) S  {
    self = [super init];

    if ( self ) {
        //DO STUFF;
        UserNAME.text = S.text;
    }

    return self;
}
```

error is on the first line:
use of undeclared identifier with initWithString
Also get should be a ; before :

Comment: Save in what manner?  Do you want them to persist between opening and closing of your app or just pass them from one view to another, or even pass them between apps?

Comment: I would just like to pass them from one view to another

Comment: I've tried a couple NSDictionarys and PLists but i could never save them in one view and write them to another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(MemberPage *)initWithString: (NSString *) s  {
    self = [super init];

    if ( self ) {
        //DO STUFF;
        UserNAME = s;
    }

    return self;
}
```

Forgot the '*'?

Comment: that didn't make a difference

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest way's I've done this in the past is just to pass them in when I create my View:

RecieverClass.m:

```
(RecieverClass*) initWithString: (NString) S  {
self = [super init];

if ( self ) {
    //DO STUFF;
    myLocalString = S;
}

return self;
}
```

SenderClass (where you create your view)

```
RecieverClass *recieverClass= [[RecieverClass alloc] initWithString:sendString];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:recieverClass animated:YES];
[recieverClass release];
```

You could pass them in as pointers or w/e really.  Just depends what you're trying to do really.

Comment: where would i input my view names (sender and the receiver) and does the capitol S matter or is that a typo

Comment: I'm getting an error with sendString,    undeclared identifyer

Comment: well, obviously you'd need to change "sendString" to the name of the string you're actually trying to send.  Maybe you should post some of your code in your opening post if you need more help.

Comment: ok, thanks i didn't even notice that, ill try it then post if i run into trouble

Answer (score 0):

I use a singleton class to share data between different views and for me it works. In the source viewController, I assign the value as a parameter to the "shared" class, and in the destination viewController I retrieve it. 
Dunno if it's the "legal" way to do it, but it's simple and it works.

Comment: I've done it this way too.  It does work and it's pretty simple.  Google sharedInstance objective C stuff and I bet you can find a pretty good example.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this tutorial: http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=1969

At a certain point you arrive at this piece of code:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
        // Custom initialization
        Model *model = [Model sharedModel];
        [model addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"text" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
    }
return self;
}
```

Adding the observer didn't immediately work for me, dunno why but I didn't look into this issue deeper. 
I changed it into:

```
 Model *model = [Model sharedModel];
 model.parameter = @"btnMainToTarget";
```

Follow the instruction from beginning till end - it will work. 
To any other people; don't hesitate to react if you didn't think my reply was accurate.

Greetings